Unable to notarize electron application using electron 11.5.0 electron-builder 22.9.1 and electron-notarize 1.0.0 as devDependency
I was able to build and notarize the electron app on MAC till April 1st, 2024, suddenly! from April 2nd I and getting below error.
Failed to upload app to Apple's notarization servers
2024-04-03 09:53:34.262 *** Error: Unable to upload your app for notarization.
2024-04-03 09:53:34.264 *** Error: Notarization of MacOS applications using altool has been decommissioned. Please use notarytool. See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3147-migrating-to-the-latest-notarization-tool (-1031)
failedTask=build stackTrace=Error: Failed to upload app to Apple's notarization servers
I am using "electron 11.5.0, electron-builder 22.9.1 and electron-notarize 1.0.0" as devdependency. note that with the same configuration it was notarizing till April 1st 2024 but failing at the signing step


macbuild@Divyas-MacBook-Air app % sudo npm run dist
nanoheal-launcher-app@4.000.000.00095.08 dist
electron-builder
electron-builder  version=22.14.13 os=22.5.0
loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
writing effective config  file=dist/builder-effective-config.yaml
packaging       platform=darwin arch=arm64 electron=11.5.0 appOutDir=dist/mac-arm64
asar usage is disabled — this is strongly not recommended  solution=enable asar and use asarUnpack to unpack files that must be externally available
asar usage is disabled — this is strongly not recommended  solution=enable asar and use asarUnpack to unpack files that must be externally available
signing         file=dist/mac-arm64/Nanoheal.app identityName=Developer ID Application: HFN, Inc (3CV9WWE69V) identityHash=980BE6C48918FDF2EB07A02884B8FB38BC86B2CC provisioningProfile=none
Failed to upload app to Apple's notarization servers
**2024-04-03 09:53:34.262 *** Error: Unable to upload your app for notarization.
2024-04-03 09:53:34.264 *** Error: Notarization of MacOS applications using altool has been decommissioned. Please use notarytool. See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3147-migrating-to-the-latest-notarization-tool (-1031)
failedTask=build stackTrace=Error: Failed to upload app to Apple's notarization servers


Please help in addressing the issue as I am not good in electron technology.
As mentioned above, I am trying to sign and notarize electron app written for MacOS using "electron 11.5.0, electron-builder 22.9.1 and electron-notarize 1.0.0" as devdependency. with this setup I my application was building and signing till April 1st 2024 but from 2nd April build is throwing error at signing step. Please help out me to address the problem that I am facing.
Thanks,
Narasimha

I have upgraded electron, electron-builder and electron_notarize  from   "devDependencies": {
"electron": "^11.5.0",
"electron-builder": "^22.9.1",
"electron-notarize": "^1.0.0"
} to "devDependencies": {
"@electron/notarize": "^2.2.1",
"electron": "^29.2.0",
"electron-builder": "^24.13.3"
}

My Notarize.js looks as below
require('dotenv').config();
const { notarize } = require('@electron/notarize');
exports.default = async function notarizing(context) {
const { electronPlatformName, appOutDir } = context;
if (electronPlatformName !== 'darwin') {
return;
}
const appName = context.packager.appInfo.productFilename;
return await notarize({
appBundleId: 'com.nanoheal.emlauncher',
appPath: ${appOutDir}/${appName}.app,
appleId: 'example.ios2@gmail.com',
appleIdPassword: 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX',
teamId :'4AB0ZZF96W'
});
};

On running "sudo npm run dist"
• signing         file=dist/mac-arm64/Nanoheal.app platform=darwin type=distribution identity=980BE6C48918FDF2EB07A02884B8FB38BC86B2CC provisioningProfile=none
• skipped macOS notarization  reason=notarize options were unable to be generated
• building        target=pkg arch=arm64 file=dist/Nanoheal-4.0.0-0.95.8-arm64.pkg

On running
spctl --assess -vv --type install Nanoheal.app
I get below message
Nanoheal.app: accepted
source=Notarized Developer ID
origin=Developer ID Application: HFN, Inc (3CV9WWE69V)
My electron app is not working it is launching with out UI elements.
when I inspect I get below call stack
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at generic.js:1:14
   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

generic.js:352 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'log2' before initialization
at getConfigData (generic.js:352:5)
at init.js:78:9

I was encountering this issue as well. I resolved it by updating my mac settings in my electron-builder.config.js file.
Specifically, I updated notarize from this:
mac: {
    ....
    notarize: true,
    ...
},

To this:
mac: {
    ....
    notarize: { 
       teamId: process.env.TEAM_ID,
    }
    ...
},

This seems to be an issue others are facing with Apple's deprecation of altool in favor of notarytool for notarization.
Found this on the electron-builder github by the way: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/7812
